# How do I prevent the access database from modifying and saving itself upon open?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

When working with an Access .accdb, every time I open the file, I see that the 'date modified' in the filesystem changes to now. This makes me nervous. I want it to stop.

I can't be the only person who has ever saved a working db, and opened it a few weeks or months later to an error. Sure, I probably have backups, and backups to my backups, and table data saved separately from my code, and version history taking up multiple gigabytes of the filesystem or in emails or where ever... but it still makes my heart jump a little whenever I see the date modified update on open, when I haven't touched the DB in some time.

Have I flipped a switch somewhere that makes it do this? Is this expected behavior? How can I stop it?

To replicate this, create a new accdb, save and close. Put something in it, nothing, or close it only a second after creating it. Open an windows explorer for the directory the accdb is saved in, and note the date modified value. Open the file at least a minute after the displayed date modified file. alt-tab back to the explorer window, and you see the date modified has changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the default behaviour, even with a native Access MDB file.  They don't work like a normal file that you have to explicitly modify to update the date - it does some things when you open it up, whether you want it to or not.

Just did a quick test - if you set the database file to read-only, it doesn't update itself.

Answer (score 0):

I construct my MS Access Applications into front end and a back end. The Front end database is made up of all the the application objects like the Queries, Forms, Reports, and Modules. The back end database is made up of the tables and links to other data sources.

Many people consider this a Microsoft Access Generally Accepted Best Practice.

So much so that Microsoft includes a Wizard to do the split for you. [Shown here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-an-Access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc)

[10 Reasons to Split an Access Database](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-plus-reasons-to-split-an-access-database)

Once the database has been split, It makes is a whole lot more manageable. The Front End can be marked read-only. The Back End remains writable.